# sRails 5 Devise after_sign_in_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Rails 5 app with Devise.  Each user has a `role_id` where they are assigned a role upon creation.  I'm trying to use the `after_sign_in_path_for` method that Devise gives to redirect to a specific page on login based on the role.

Below is what I have so far, but it doesn't work when trying to sign out a disabled user.

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource.role_id
      when Role.find_by(name: "admin").id
      root_path
      when Role.find_by(name: "disabled").id
      destroy_user_session_path
      else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

I'm able to sign in when I'm an admin user and it redirects.  But if I try to sign in as a user whose role is disabled, it tries to tear down the session then raises an exception of `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"`.  I know the method `destroy_user_session_path` expects a `delete` method but how can I pass this in the application controller?

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

I tried the `sign_out(resource)` as suggested in the first answer, and it raises an exception `undefined method`to_model' for true:TrueClass`in my`my_sessions_controller.rb` which I use to override the create method to set a login token and limit concurrent sessions.  Here is the controller.

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_action :check_concurrent_session

  def create
    super
    set_login_token
  end

  private
  def set_login_token
    token = Devise.friendly_token
    session[:token] = token
    current_user.login_token = token
    current_user.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check roles inside MySessionsController#create and prevent logging if the role not valid instead of allowing user to login then logout

```
def create 
 unless current_user.role_id == Role.find_by(name: "disabled").id 
  super set_login_token 
 else 
  redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: "You can't log in"    
  end 
end
```

You can also use active_for_authentication? and inactive_message methods in user model to prevent him from login. in `/app/models/user.rb`:

```
def active_for_authentication?
 super and self.role_id != Role.find_by(name: "disabled").id 
end

def inactive_message
 "You can't log in"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what would this look like in the `create` method if I'm checking the role?  So far this is what I've come up with and it's not working properly. `def create
    unless current_user.role_id == Role.find_by(name: "disabled").id
      super
      set_login_token
    end
  end`

Comment: Add `else redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: "You can't log in" end`

Comment: can you edit your answer to show the proper controller method instead of fragments in comments here?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, overriding the create method didn't work and kept the user logged in.  Setting the model methods in `user.rb` gave me the functionality I needed.  Thanks so much, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**destroy_user_session_path** is making `[GET] "/users/sign_out"` request.

You can use `sign_out` or `reset_session` function to delete session directly.

Hope this answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use devise's sign_out(resource) method instead of destroy_user_session_path. This method will destroy the user session.

Comment: Using `sign_out(resource)` results in an exception raised `undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass`

Comment: It's calling super on the create action in the `my_sessions_controller` which I have setup to set a login token to limit concurrent sessions.  I'll add the controller to my original question so you can see it.

Comment: sign_out method should not call sessions_controller#create. Are you sure that you have not overridden sign_out method in any of other helpers? According to your issue, why sign_in the user if not needed in the first place. Don't sign_in the user if your user role is disabled.  You can do it in create method of your custom session controller

Comment: The sign_out method is not overridden in any other helpers in my app.  Can you elaborate on how I would deny the disabled user role in my custom session controller create action?